# How can I remove one option from a multiple select box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Say I have a select2 box like this:

[image: Select2 Options]

I want to remove the option '_Primary Care' (has option value 1), how do I go about doing this? I can clear all selected options by doing:

```
$('#categories-ids').val(null).trigger('change');
```

But I am not sure how to remove just one value.

Comment: Apologies, this is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/q/22159247/1536095

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$("#categories-ids option[value='1']").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/2q2836xm/

```
var $select = $('#select');
var idToRemove = 'c4';

var values = $select.val();
if (values) {
    var i = values.indexOf(idToRemove);
    if (i >= 0) {
        values.splice(i, 1);
        $select.val(values).change();
    }
}
```